# Обе или оба?

Tags: числительные

Как образуется числительное "оба" в зависимости от пола?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь о двух мужчинах, то — *оба*.
Если речь о двух женщинах, то — *обе*.
А если речь идёт о мужчине и женщине?

Answer (score 0):

Числительное "оба", уважаемая Fuchoin Kazuki, никак не образуется. Оно употребляется со всеми существительными, кроме существительных женского рода. Например, об обОИХ карандашах (р.п. скольких? - обОИХ, тв. п.сколькими? - обОИМИ).
Числительное "обе" употребляется только с существительными женского рода. Даже если речь идёт не "о двух женщинах", tiger, а например, об обЕИХ ручках (р.п. скольких? - обЕИХ, тв. п.сколькими? - обЕИМИ).

Comment: А "Uchoin Kazuki" при чем?

Comment: Ни при чём абсолютно. Тысяча извинений (неправильно скопировала). Это была Fuchoin Kazuki. Спасибо, Вам, бегемотик.

Comment: Гм... 1. Извиняться не надо, лучше ответьте по существу. При чем здесь Fuchoin Kazuki (это бывший модератор)? Автор вопроса - et-backers  2. "бегемотиков" на форуме не люблю. Не потому, что напыщенный сноб, а потому, что это коверканье ника, не все потом понимают, о ком речь. Извиняться тоже не надо.

Comment: Отвечаю по существу вопроса. Так как вопрос отредактирован и сформулирован бывшим модератором Fuchoin Kazuki (изменён 07. 05.), я обращаюсь именно к нему, подчёркивая таким образом, что формулировка неграмотна. Не может образование числительного зависеть от пола. Ник обещаю впредь не коверкать, мне тоже обращение "бегемотик" не нравится.

Comment: Тогда Вы неправы. Обращаться надо к автору. Модератор (и любой другой пользователь) может изменить формулировку, но уж за то, что он **не менял** никакой ответственности нести не может.